# How can I adapt the size of the recyclerview according to the children shown in this

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to show a reclycer view but that it adapts to the height of the children because there are other elements below the reclycer view.
When the reclycer view is configured with a "match_parent" height, it shows the number of children within it, but it occupies the entire screen and the idea is: that as there are children, the reclycler view will load on the screen

Then I leave my layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Cesta_Activity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Mis_Pedidos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Cesta"
        android:text="Mis Pedidos"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/Letra"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cesta_mas"
        android:drawablePadding="25dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Nombre_Restaurante"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Restaurante"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Mis_Pedidos">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/Reclycer_Cesta"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Mis_Pedidos"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Btn_Ordenar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Edt_Observación"
            android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
            android:background="@drawable/boton_redondeado"
            android:text="añadir a la cesta"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

With this code doesn't show nothing inside of reclyclerview

Comment: You can use the recycler view inside a constraint layout, give it a top and bottom constraint while using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: if you want to dynamically adjust the size as soon as an item is added to the list, then you may want to look at fragments and how to use fragments with recycler views

Comment: Yes, I want to dynamically see the children that exist in the reclycler view, that is, it must be the size of the list of children that are within the reclycler view